# Nested Doctype tags

Tags: xhtml, html

Let's say I begin an HTML file with the usual DOCTYPE declaration.  However, let's also assume that another instance of a DOCTYPE tag is introduced inside the body of that document via some soft of included content (eg. a content template).

From my testing this doesn't seem to be a problem.  But I was wondering if anyone know of a situation where this would cause problems?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

The `<DOCTYPE>` declaration is required to be the first thing in the document. I don't even think it tolerates whitespace before it very well. Subsequent DOCTYPE declarations will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I suspected that was the case.